# Simple conversion of boolean vector to string vector with for loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm pretty new to R and just about an hour in.

I have a simple vector for positive profit margin for a month that returns 12 items as either True or False and have called this vector good_months

I'm trying to generate a similar vector that returns the equivalent month name for all values that are true.

For example:

```
Good months 
TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# which represents positive profit margins for Jan, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sept, Dec
```

I've written a simple for loop, but unfortunately it returns a single vector. How would I correct this?

```
list_of_good_months <- c()
length(list_of_good_months)

for(i in 1:12){
  if(good_months[i] == TRUE){
    list_of_good_months[i] <- months[i]
  }
  else{
    list_of_good_months[i] <- " "
  }
}

list_good_months
length(list_of_good_months)
```

Console Output:

```
**[1] 0
> 
> for(i in 1:12){
+   if(good_months[i] == TRUE){
+     list_of_good_months[i] <- months[i]
+   }
+   else{
+     list_of_good_months[i] <- " "
+   }
+ }
> 
> list_good_months
[1] "Sep"
> length(list_of_good_months)
[1] 12**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is a vectorised language, very rarely you'll need to write an explicit `for` loop to achieve your goal.

There is inbuilt vector `month.abb` and `month.name` which you can use here and subset them using the logical values in `good_months`.

```
good_months <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE)

list_of_good_months  <- month.abb[good_months]
list_of_good_months
#[1] "Jan" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Dec"
```

---

To replace `FALSE` value with blanks you can use -

```
list_of_good_months <- month.abb
list_of_good_months[!good_months] <- ''
list_of_good_months

# [1] "Jan" ""    ""    ""    ""    "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" ""    ""    "Dec"
```

Comment: If I wanted to capture the data in a matrix, is it possible to replace all false items with blank spaces?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply extract good months with `TRUE`, `FALSE` vector as:

```
months[good_months]
```